# Pdf pages orientation issues in OCR

Tags: r, ocr, tesseract

I  have some documents which have orientation issues, like 1st page is vertical, second  and third is horizontal, then again comes vertical. There is no such fix pattern, any page can have any orientation in the documents.

In some pdf, two pages are scanned together on one page. Some are vertical and some are horizontal.

Can we do OCR and extract information from  these documents through R?

Comment: It is possible. Could you give us an example? Can you provide a link to a PDF file that has this kind of issue?